# link-to with query-params in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, query-string

I'm trying to pass some query parameters as a component parameter and then use it on a `link-to`.

```
{{activities/list-item
  model=submission
  task=model
  parent=parent
  group=model.group
  activitiesShowRoute=(concat "assignments.show.tasks.discuss.show." (pluralize submission.type) ".show")
  queryParams=(query-params allocation_id="all")
}}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
{{#link-to activitiesShowRoute group parent task model queryParams}}Click{{/link-to}}
```

It works as expected, the problem is that if I call the component with no value in `queryParams` then the generated link has `href='#'` instead of the desired route without the query parameter.

I don't want to have an `{{#if queryParams}}` outside of link because in reality the content of my link is quite complex and I don't what to repeat everything.

Can I get it to behave as I want?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The modern angle bracket version of `<LinkTo>` supports a hash with the query params:

```
<LinkTo @route="posts" @query={{hash direction="asc"}}>Sort</LinkTo>
```

This is not only more future proof and the current recommended way but also reduces complexity in your specific scenario as you don't need to use `{{query-params}}` helper anymore.

Applied to your code it would look like this:

```
{{activities/list-item
  model=submission
  task=model
  parent=parent
  group=model.group
  activitiesShowRoute=(concat "assignments.show.tasks.discuss.show." (pluralize submission.type) ".show")
  queryParams=(hash allocation_id="all")
}}
```

```
<LinkTo
  @route={{@activitiesShowRoute}}
  @models={{@array @group @parent @task @model}}
  @queryParams={{@queryParams}}
>
  Click
</LinkTo>
```

You can further simplify the API if you alter the public API of `{{activities/list-item}}` (or `<Activities::ListItem>` in angle bracket syntax) to directly accept `@route`, `@models` and `@queryParams` arguments.

The angle bracket versions of built-in components are available since Ember 3.10. See [release notes](https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/05/21/ember-3-10-released.html) for details. They are part of the [Ember Octane edition](https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/12/20/octane-is-here.html).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't migrate the project to the new version of Ember

Answer (score 0):

Add a permanent unused query parameter

```
queryParams=(query-params foo="bar")
```

Comment: Adding something unnecessary to the url the user will see is far from ideal, but thanks

Comment: This also won't work in the future, as the `query-param` helper was removed in Ember 4.0